# Icefaces with Richfaces, configuration

Tags: jsf, richfaces, icefaces

I am very new to JSF and working on one Project.

I am already using jsf-api and jsf-api-impl of mojarra version 2.0.

Also I am using Richfaces and my web.xml mapping is like,

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Everything is working at this point.
I have one requirement where I need to use Icefaces for providing user to upload Video as what told by my manager.

So I downloaded jar from 
http://www.icesoft.org/java/downloads/icefaces-downloads.jsf of version 3

Now, I have added only icefaces.jar, icefaces-ace.jar to my project.

Now, after adding jar in lib folder and not modifying any thing in my project, I run the project.

Working project is not working now, I mean for few links where action was happening previously now it is not happening now and i think it is getting intercepted by Icefaces classes.

I am not sure of this issue, also I am not getting much info on logs.

So, can we use Icefaces and Rich Faces both in one project?
If we need to use both what configuration specific things one has to do?

Comment: I'm not a JSF expert, but I would guess that it's either/or.  They are different implementations of the same API, so you'll have one or the other in the CLASSPATH.  Anything else results in a conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Richfaces and Icefaces do not go together. However, since you are using JSF 2 (so Richfaces 4 I guess) you can use both Richfaces and Primefaces. In fact, using Primefaces requires only adding the jar to your CLASSPATH.